# Codeforces Round #322 (Div. 2) - B O(n) but still overtime

Tags: java, algorithm

The problem: http://codeforces.com/contest/581/problem/B

My code is O(n), and I compared my code with others, cannot understand why my code exceeds the time limit in test case 6 (with n = 100,000)? Any idea?

```
 private void solve() throws IOException {
    //String s = nextToken();
    int n = nextInt();

    int[] array = new int[n];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       array[i] = nextInt();
   }

   int max = -1;
   String ans = "";
   for (int i = array.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
       if (array[i] >= max) {
           max = array[i];
           ans = 0 + " " + ans;
       }
       else {
           ans = ( max - array[i] +1) + " " + ans ;
       }
   }


   writer.println(ans.substring(0,ans.length()-1));


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not O(n); `+` on a `String` is O(n) and your code is O(n^2).  You'd need to use `StringBuilder` instead.

Additionally, inserting at the beginning instead of the end is also generally bad, so even `StringBuilder` won't let you do that efficiently.

You'll need to figure out how to build the answer the other way around.

Comment: Because it does O(n) usages of string concatenation, each of which is O(n).

Comment: ahhhhh, spot on!! Thank you so much!